# C++ unused variable warning even when I returned it at the end of function

Tags: c++

```
Table::Table(int n): maxGuests(n)
{
    int numGuests = 0;
}
int Table::maxOccupancy(void)
{
    return maxGuests;
}

int Table::currentOccupancy(void)
{
    return numGuests;
}
```

As in the above code, I'm getting an unused `numGuests` warning, even after returning it at the end of my accessor. Why would that be?

Thanks :)

Comment: You should quote --- verbatim --- the warning message the compiler give you and show the line it is reported to.

Comment: What do you think `int numGuests = 0;` does in your constructor?

Comment: Thankfully your compiler tells you this is a problem.

Comment: This warning is really an error. Its a good job the compiler found it and told you about otherwise your code would not work as expected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the code

```
Table::Table(int n): maxGuests(n)
{
int numGuests = 0;
}
```

A local variable `numGuests` is defined, which is not the class property. And this is not used anywhere. Hence you are getting the warning.
Remove `int` in the statement `int numGuests = 0;` should resolve this problem.

OR better you can update your code to include this property in the initializer list itself like:

```
Table::Table(int n) : maxGuests(n), numGuests(0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The local variable `numGuests` in the snippet

```
Table::Table(int n): maxGuests(n)
{
    int numGuests = 0;
}
```

has not been used. Presumably you want instead

```
struct Table
{
    ...
    int numGuests = 0;      // default value
    const int maxGuests;
    Table(int n) : maxGuests(n) {}
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You create a local variable with the same name as a class member. Just remove `int` to get what you want:

```
Table::Table(int n): maxGuests(n)
{
    numGuests = 0;
}
```

Comment: Even better would be to move the initialization to the initialization list rather than the constructor body.

Comment: @MananShah the @Walter 's answer is more detailed. You can initialize simple type right in declaration or if you don't want for any reasons, you can do it before constructor's body like this: `Table::Table(int n): maxGuests(n), numGuests(0) { }`

Comment: @JesperJuhl What about the word *before*? Unfortunately I am not English native speaker, and sometimes I forget the terminology. So if the initialization list isn't located before the constructor's body, where is it located?

Comment: @LexSergeev  Just my opinion, on the topic, but what is wrong with the construct _rather than_? In this context, it means "_instead of_". And the position of initialization list, relative to the constructor body, isn't relevant, while the word _before_ would make it seem that it is, while, simultaneously, not conveying the same information, as "_rather than_". Note: I am not a native English speaker as well.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius My second comment was about Jesper's note which is already deleted

Comment: While this "fixes" the code in the question, it suggest poor style. Member variables should be initialized as early as possible, while here this is done late.

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a variable that "shadows" the property you're trying to assign. I'm not sure why you're using two completely different initialization methods here, but you can simplify the code and fix the bug like this:

```
Table::Table(int n) : maxGuests(n), numGuests(0)
{
}
```

Whenever practical, initialize your properties like that. Doing it in code is usually reserved for cases where it's not clear what value will be assigned, some computation is required, or you need to delegate to a function to do it.